# Environment variable PATH_INFO not defined by lighttpd using uwsgi module

Tags: python, uwsgi, bottle, lighttpd

I have lighttpd version 1.4.73 running on Alpine Linux. I enabled `mod_scgi` and added this to my configuration file:

```
scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"
scgi.server = (
    "/tp2/" => ( "tp2-app" => (
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
          "port" => 8080,
          "check-local" => "disable",
          "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
          "fix_root_path_name" => "enable"
        )
    ),
)
```

My [Bottle.py crashes because it can't find `PATH_INFO`](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L966). I reduced the problem to this minuscle pure Python wsgi application that displays the request's environment variables:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8')])

    page = [f'@Hello World!\n'.encode("utf-8")]
    for key, value in environ.items():
        page.append(f"{key} = {value}\n".encode("utf-8"))

    return sorted(page)
```

I run this app with:

```
uwsgi --uwsgi-socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --plugin python3 -w hello_world_app
```

And indeed, `PATH_INFO` is not set by lighttpd:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 943
Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2024 18:22:09 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.73

@Hello World!
CONTENT_LENGTH = 0
DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/localhost/htdocs
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT = */*
HTTP_HOST = tp2.test
HTTP_USER_AGENT = curl/8.5.0
QUERY_STRING = date=2024-03-24T14:22:10-04:00
REDIRECT_STATUS = 200
REMOTE_ADDR = 192.168.3.10
REMOTE_PORT = 35690
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
REQUEST_SCHEME = http
REQUEST_URI = /tp2/hello?date=2024-03-24T14:22:10-04:00
SCRIPT_FILENAME = /var/www/localhost/htdocs/tp2/hello
SCRIPT_NAME = /tp2/hello
SERVER_ADDR = 192.168.3.30
SERVER_NAME = tp2.test
SERVER_PORT = 80
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SOFTWARE = lighttpd/1.4.73
uwsgi.node = b'tp2.test'
uwsgi.version = b'2.0.23'
```

How can I forward everything under the path `/tp2/` to my application and have `PATH_INFO` available for Bottle?

Answer (score 1):

[lighttpd gateway server host options](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ConfigurationOptions#gw_backend-gateway-server-host-options)

If `"check-local" => "disable"`, then lighttpd does not check the URL against the filesystem under the document-root and does not generate `PATH_INFO`, as `PATH_INFO` is the part of the url-path after the script name, and lighttpd has been told not to check the local filesystem, and instead to treat the entire url-path in the request as `SCRIPT_NAME`.

`PATH_INFO`: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875.html#section-4.1.5

If you are using `"check-local" => "disable"` then your script should be looking at the request that was made, not `PATH_INFO`.  e.g. `SCRIPT_NAME` and `QUERY_STRING`, or the non-standard `REQUEST_URI` provided by lighttpd, which contains `SCRIPT_NAME`, optional `PATH_INFO`, and `QUERY_STRING`.

Practical answer: if you remove `"check-local" => "disable"` from your configuration and you touch an otherwise empty file named `tp2` under your `server.document-root`, then `PATH_INFO` might be generated in the way you want.

(Alternatively, fix your uwscgi app to not rely on `PATH_INFO` and you can keep `"check-local" => "disable"`)

---

`"fix-root-scriptname" => "enable"` is for when the `scgi.server` is handling `"/"` (root of the path), which does not apply to `"/tp2/"` so this does not appear to have any effect in your configuration.

---

What is `"fix_root_path_name" => "enable"`?  Where did you find that or cut-n-paste that?  (Hint: it is not valid)

Comment: Another option: You might try setting `environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['SCRIPT_NAME']` before invoking the bottle app.

Comment: Curious: will the app work if you specify `setenv.set-environment = ("PATH_INFO" => "")` in your lighttpd.conf?  That should get you past the bottle crash, but will the app work?  (Should `bottle.py` handle if the `PATH_INFO` variable is not set, rather than an empty value?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but they don't work. With `check-local` enabled I never reach my server. `PATH_INFO` is not use in that many places, but a quick hardcode of `/tp2/`  or `SCRIPT_NAME` here and there produced different errors. I think I'll open an issue in the project.

Comment: As for `fix_root_path_name`, I gave it a try after it came up as I was searching the source with `grep -r fix.root lighttpd1.4`.